# C array of pointers to structs realloc() error

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, dynamic-allocation

I'm trying to make a Huffman code to practice C coding and I keep geting the same error.

Let me explain the code. 
First it creates the struct below:

```
struct sNo {
    int valor;
    char letra;
    struct sNo *esq;
    struct sNo *dir;
};
typedef struct sNo sNo;
```

Then it creates an array of structs ('No'):

```
sNo *No;
No = calloc(qtd_no, sizeof(sNo));
```

It reads a string from the keyboard placing in this array the letter and the ammount of times it appears. Like the representation below with the word 'abracadabra':

```
No:    a/5 b/2 r/2 c/1 d/1
```

Now, to make a Huffman tree, it's needed that I create another array ('pNo'), with pointers to the original array:

```
int qtd_pno = qtd_no;
sNo **pNo;
pNo = calloc(qtd_pno, sizeof(sNo*));
for (i = 0; i < qtd_pno; i++){
    pNo[i] = &No[i];    
}
```

The two arrays appear like that:

```
No:    a/5 b/2 r/2 c/1 d/1  
pNo:   a/5 b/2 r/2 c/1 d/1
```

After that it can sort the array of pointers like below without changing the original one:

```
No:    a/5 b/2 r/2 c/1 d/1  
pNo:   c/1 d/1 r/2 b/2 a/5
```

But when it tries to increase the size of the 'No' array...

```
qtd_no++;
No = realloc(No,(sizeof(sNo) * qtd_no));
```

... this is what happens with the arrays:

```
No:    a/5 b/2 r/2 c/1 d/1  /0
pNo:   c/1 d/1 r/2 b/2 /0
```

or something like that:

```
No:    a/5 b/2 r/2 c/1 d/1  /0
pNo:   c/1 d/1 r/2 b/2 �/1288268632
```

Note that I'm not changing anything on the 'pNo' array, but somehow the value pointed is. I think it could be some specific characteristic of dynamic memory allocation, but I'm not sure.

EDIT
The complete code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


//Definicao do tipo struct No
struct sNo {
    int valor;
    char letra;
    struct sNo *esq;
    struct sNo *dir;
};
typedef struct sNo sNo;


//Funcoes
void SelectionSort(sNo *A[], int qtd_no);
void ImprimeArvore (sNo *a);


int main(){
    //Variaveis auxiliares
    int i, j;


    //Leitura de texto do teclado
    char texto[30];
    printf("Digite frase \n");
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    fgets(texto, 30, stdin);

    //Criacao dos nos
    int qtd_no = 0;
    sNo *No;

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(texto) && texto[i] != '\0'; i++){

        if(texto[i] >= 32){

            if(i == 0){

                qtd_no++;
                No = calloc(qtd_no, sizeof(sNo));
                if(No == NULL){
                    printf("Erro: memoria insuficiente\n");
                    exit(1);
                }

                No[i].letra = texto[i];
                No[i].valor = 1;
                No[i].esq = NULL;
                No[i].dir = NULL;
                printf("%d\t%c %c\t%d\n", i, texto[i], No[i].letra, No[i].valor);

            }else{

                for(j = 0; j <= qtd_no - 1; j++){

                    if(texto[i] == No[j].letra){
                        No[j].valor++;
                        printf("%d %d\t%c %c\t%d\n", i, j, texto[i], No[j].letra, No[j].valor);
                        break;

                    } 

                    else if(j == qtd_no - 1){

                        qtd_no++;
                        No = realloc(No,(sizeof(sNo) * qtd_no));
                        if(No == NULL){
                            printf("Erro: memoria insuficiente\n");
                            exit(1);
                        }

                        No[j+1].letra = texto[i];
                        No[j+1].valor = 1;
                        No[j+1].esq = NULL;
                        No[j+1].dir = NULL;
                        printf("%d %d\t%c %c\t%d\n", i, j, texto[i], No[j+1].letra, No[j+1].valor);
                        break;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Criacao de array com ponteiros para nos
    int qtd_pno = qtd_no;

    sNo **pNo;
    pNo = calloc(qtd_pno, sizeof(sNo*));
    if(pNo == NULL){
        printf("Erro: memoria insuficiente\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < qtd_pno; i++){
        pNo[i] = &No[i];    
    }

    //Organizacao dos nos pelo valor
    SelectionSort(pNo, qtd_pno);

    //Criacao da arvore binaria
    while(qtd_pno > 1){

        qtd_no++;

        No = realloc(No,(sizeof(sNo) * qtd_no));
        if(No == NULL){
            printf("Erro: memoria insuficiente\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        No[qtd_no - 1].letra = '\0';
        No[qtd_no - 1].valor = (pNo[0]->valor) + (pNo[1]->valor);
        No[qtd_no - 1].esq = pNo[0];
        No[qtd_no - 1].dir = pNo[1];

        if(qtd_pno > 2){
            for(i = 0; i <= qtd_pno-2; i++){
                pNo[i] = pNo[i+2];
            }
        }

        qtd_pno--;
        pNo = realloc(pNo,(sizeof(sNo*) * qtd_pno));
        pNo[qtd_pno - 1] = &No[qtd_no - 1];

        if(qtd_pno > 1){
            SelectionSort(pNo, qtd_pno);
        }
    }

    sNo *raiz;
    raiz = pNo[0];
    free(pNo);

    printf("\n%s\n", texto);

    ImprimeArvore(raiz);
    printf("\n");

}

//Funcao de organizacao por valor
void SelectionSort(sNo *A[], int qtd_pno){

    sNo *temp;
    int i, j, Imin;

    for(i = 0; i < qtd_pno - 1; i++){
        Imin = i;
        for(j = i + 1; j < qtd_pno; j++){
            if((A[j]->valor) < (A[Imin]->valor)){
                Imin = j;
            }
        }

        temp = A[Imin];
        A[Imin] = A[i];
        A[i] = temp;
    }
}


void ImprimeArvore(sNo *a){

    if(a->letra) printf ("<%c/%d", (a->letra), (a->valor));
    else printf ("<_/%d", (a->valor));  

    if(a->esq != NULL) ImprimeArvore (a->esq);
    if(a->dir != NULL) ImprimeArvore (a->dir);

    printf (">");

}
```

Comment: `realloc` just reallocates more memory, but it doesn't _initialize_ the newly allocated memory. The zeros or the strange values you see are indeterminate values. Best you post a [mcve].

Comment: ... also `realloc()` "invalidates" the pointer's value passed in, and with doing so all other copies of the "original" value as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that `realloc` does not make any guarantees about expanding your array in place.

> to make a Huffman tree, it's needed that I create another array ('pNo'), with pointers to the original array

Since you have pointers to `calloc`-ed array inside other `struct sNo` objects, calling `realloc` on the block that has these structures may invalidate all external pointers to these structures. That is why your code runs into undefined behavior after a call to `realloc`.

One approach to fixing this problem is to store indexes instead of pointers. This works, as long as you keep a single dynamic array to which you add new items, but never remove items from it.